# How to refresh generated vdi image in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I generate a VDI hdd image with a script.

As i am in tuning process, i regenerate it very often.

Each time the VDI is regenerated, VirtualBox did not recognize the disk anymore and i have to remove it, reenter the new file and associate it with my VM:

```
$ VBoxManage startvm iso-debian

Waiting for VM "iso-debian" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: Could not open the medium '/path/to/myimage.vdi'.
VBoxManage: error: VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file '/path/to/myimage.vdi' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
```

The file exists but i presume its UUID or some metadata has changed so it is not found by VirtualBox.

Is there a more convenient way (through VBoxManage) to tell VirtualBox to refresh its VDI database ?

Something like:

```
$ VBoxManage update-vdi-metadata /path/to/myimage.vdi
```

or something else i can put in a bash script to avoid having to make all theses steps manually.

Comment: Just looked at the documentation: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html Maybe something like `VBoxManage storageattach ... --medium none` `VBoxManage storageattach ... --medium filename`?

Comment: @Bodo yeah you put me to the path!

Answer (score 0):

So thank to the comment of @Bodo here is the solution:

Detach the medium from the VM:

```
$ VBoxManage storageattach iso-debian --storagectl SATA --port 0 --type hdd --medium none
```

Remove the medium from VirtualBox:

```
$ VBoxManage closemedium /path/to/image.vdi
```

Attach again the image:

```
$ VBoxManage storageattach iso-debian --storagectl SATA --port 0 --type hdd --medium /path/to/image.vdi
```